# Refresh only one level on Flexicious Datagrid

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, datagrid, flexicious

Using ultimate flexicious datagrid with enableDynamicLevels="true", I search a way to refresh one dynamic level created on flexicious datagrid.
I can't use rebuidBody function because it's a dynamic level created with custom children function.

Is it possible ?

Thanks for answer

Comment: Send a message to our support with a test case and they will be able to assist you.

Answer (score 0):

If you are only trying to expand or collapse 1 item, you can call `grid.expandChildrenOf(yourItem, expandOrCollapse)`